# A fatal error occurred while reading the input stream from the network. The session will be terminated (input error: 109, output error: 0)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, iis

Getting the following error from SQL Server 2008:

> A fatal error occurred while reading the input stream from the
>   network. The session will be terminated (input error: 109, output
>   error: 0).

I am running Windows 7 Pro 64 BIT / 12 GIG RAM, IIS.

Under light load (1 request per second) I get the above error, not sure why.

I am using LoadUI (as this is a service based app) to execute the same request 1 per second.  Which works fine. Now if I make another request from a Web App then I get the above error message, IIS Process's memory jumps (can carries on) from couple of hundred meg to 9 GIG in matter of 5 seconds.

It appears that SQL Server cannot handle the amount of requests/connections on Windows 7, I am hoping I will not see this in PROD.

Any help would be great.

Paul.

Comment: Found the problem, I am using PostSharp that records error to the SQL Database.  Not sure why though.  I can now do 108 requests per second without any problems.